# How do you send an array of qubits to an operation in Q#?

Tags: programming, q#

I have the following operation in my .qs files:

```
operation myOp(qubits: Qubit[]) : () {
     // uses elements from the qubit array        
 }
```

How do I send an array of qubits to this in the driver file?
The following did not work:

```
Qubit[] qubits = new Qubit[2];
myOp.Run(sim, qubits);
```

I got the following error:

```
Driver.cs(13,32): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.Qubit[]' to 'Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.QArray<Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.Qubit>' [/home/tinkidinki/Quantum/Warmup_Contest/BellState/BellState.csproj]

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
```

*Also, as an aside: Would such a question be more suitable for this site, or for stack overflow?*

Comment: Hi @Tinkidinki! Welcome to Quantum Computing Stack Exchange. Yes, questions related to quantum programming are on-topic.

Comment: A similar question was asked on [Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/60209?#comment-441424). It's said that creating Qubits in C# is impossible and one has to write tests in Q# instead. But as for the specific compilation error, it's probably fixed by something like `myOp.Run(sim, new QArray(qubits));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, [there are exactly two ways to allocate qubits in Q#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-techniques-5-workingwithqubits?view=qsharp-preview#allocating-qubits): the `using` statement, and the `borrowing` statement.
Both can only be used from within Q#, and can't be directly used from within C#.
Thus, you'd likely want to make a new Q# operation to serve as the "entry point" from C#; this new operation would then be responsible for allocating qubits and passing them down.

For instance:

```
// MyOp.qs
operation EntryPoint() : () {
    body {
        using (register = Qubit[2]) {
            myOp(register);
        }
    }
}


// Driver.cs
EntryPoint.Run().Wait();
```

Answer (score 3):

All qubits must be allocated by the `Simulator`, so you can't create an instance and pass it down to your Operation.

Why do you want to create the `Qubits` on the driver? If anything, you should create an "entry" method on Q# that just allocates your qubits and then call your `operation`, and call that from the Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can allocate qubits from C#! After all, Q# compiles to C#, so it's not possible for something to be doable *only* from Q#.

[Here's a small script I wrote that will show you the C# generated from a Q# file.](https://tio.run/##tZLBTsMwDIbPzVNYYlK3Q5NtCIRgcBuI05jEDe2QpW4XrU3SxB0a0GcfbacBRyTEwVGc3/ZnR34Lm4OSBHfgvM29LHkVYDaL54v7@CDE8gweLAbQBmijA2Qai5QzZmSJwUmF8Py4YO8ssg69JG0NzA35/ZPVhoYjuIb2aOVobdN9f4nqoE0OQ4@5DoQebmFZrzW9TFfHyCgq9wv3pY9uureG9dYwFmW1UT2oD6u63NByjkVWJ2TDmkM7A0stGSQQ1pEotfI22IzExpYouKlzJNFOsZU5hm@ZV7U0VJc8xR0W1pVoiG81iTGf8snV@JJPLsbnifO40/gqyNoiiCqoznhaFJAkHjP0aFT7dYNhpk36rx0Ueg0fkHt0ELf8QTz6G1VJY83vWUmijavpxwYx1u3Uyc@5CodP)

The relevant bit is `Allocate.Apply`, which allocates the qubits, and you can read the rest of the produced code to see where `Allocate` comes from.

With that in mind, *should* you be allocating qubits from C#? Well, no, probably not. It's annoyingly difficult, and it's best to leave the quantum stuff for a quantum language.